# GAE Frontend Instance Hours increase without clear reason

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've noticed a strange phenomenon on my GAE app: the Frontend Instance Hours are increasing throughout the day, even though there are no incoming requests.

I [read](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/billing#instance_request) here that two possible reasons for this are 1) cron jobs and 2) Datastore Admin is enabled.

However, I have neither cron jobs nor Datastore Admin enabled, making this increase all the more mysterious.

Can anyone explain why this might be happening?

Comment: What is your idle instances setting to in the Application settings?

Comment: Ryan, can you add more details about your problem? e.g: Application settings, Graphs (traffic/latency/errors/instances) showing the increase, among others.

Comment: @Keith - Idle Instances are set at "( 1 – Automatic )" and warmup requests are not enabled.

Comment: @Jose Thanks for your reply. The graphs over the period of interest are as follows: Traffic: Nothing; latency: flat line around ~300;  errors: Nothing; instances: at one the whole time. Furthermore, the instance is classified as 'billed' but not 'active'. Memory usage is 37.5MB the whole time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Idle Instances set to "1 - automatic" it means that you have an instance ready to go all the time - which means that it is consuming instance hours. If you do not want to incur any cost when not in use, you should set it to "automatic - automatic". However, there will then be a spin-up time when the first request comes in.